# Javascript, switching images through both mouseover and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, mouseover

I have some buttons( "ul.subjects li" ) and...
1. change buttons' background-images through mouseover actions
2. can be clicked one button at once.
　So once clicked a button, others are cancelled.
I have two this button lists and switch contents by clicked items(subjects and ages).

I can switch background-images by changing "class" of  (class="mat" to class="mat_c").

```
$(function(){
    $(document).delegate("ul.subjects li a", "mouseover", function(){
        $(this).data("imgc", $(this).attr("class"));
        var regex = /_s/;
        if (regex.test($(this).data("imgc")) == false ) {
        $(this).attr("class", $(this).data("imgc")+"_c")
        }
    });
    $(document).delegate("ul.subjects li a", "mouseout", function(){
        $(this).attr("class", $(this).attr("class").replace(/_c/, ""));
    });
});

<ul class="subjects">
    <li><a id="mat" class="mat" href="/age=all/sub=mat/"></a>算数・数学</li>
    <li><a id="soc" class="soc" href="/age=all/sub=soc/"></a>社会</li>
    <li><a id="sci" class="sci" href="/age=all/sub=sci/"></a>理科</li>
    <li><a id="eng" class="eng" href="/age=all/sub=eng/"></a>英語</li>
</ul>
```

While button-click action doesn't work right, trying to change attribute into class="..._s",

but immediately changed into class="..._c".

```
$(function(){
    $(document).delegate("ul.subjects li a", "click", function(){
        $("ul.subjects").html($("ul.subjects").html().replace(/_s/g, ""));
        $(this).attr("class", $(this).attr("class").replace(/_c/, "_s"));
    });
});
```

Maybe I should control the events or order of them...
and there should be more simple ways to do this. How should I figure this out?

As you can see it on http://jsfiddle.net/MsdGS/1/, 
After you click the under list ,  mouseover action doesn't work right.
Clicked buttons' "class" should be changed to "..._s",
(class="mat" to class="mat_s")
but "..._s" immediately changed to "..._c".

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe you've some example on e.g. jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @ted Thanks! I tried to test my code.

Comment: I meant: if you would post some example it is much easier to help. For example like this http://jsfiddle.net/VqPEq/5/

Comment: I tried jsfiddle with full code and scripts.http://jsfiddle.net/MsdGS/1/

Comment: @koichi_n can you provide correct urls for images backgrounds? Cause now you jsfiddle is not much useful

Comment: Thanks @caligula, but I tested on local environment.
And it's hard to upload images now.So I put borders on images.

Comment: @koichi_n it seems that mouseover is triggered when mouse is moved on the elements..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The result](http://jsfiddle.net/MsdGS/13/) (i've removed the `href` in the bottom `ul` list)

If i have understood your question correct this is what you need to change:

```
$(function(){
    $("#course_tb").load("/age=all/sub=all/"+"#course_tb");
    $(document).delegate("ul.subjects li a", "click", function(){
        // iterate through `subjects`'s "a"
        $("ul.subjects li a").each(function(index, el){
            $(el).attr("class", $(el).attr("class").replace(/_s/g, ""));
        });
        //html($("ul.subjects").html().replace(/_s/g, ""));
        // ...
        return false;
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `hover` to implement mouseover and mouseout, like

```
  $("ul.subjects li a").hover(function() {
      $(this).css("background-image", "www.google.com");
     }, function() {
      $(this).css("background-image", "www.google.com");
     });
```

As you can see, just try to use `css:background-image` to directly change the background image. This would bypass your problem.

Hope this works for you.

[.hover() API](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)